# No auto-brightness option in LG L90 dual

Tags: screen-brightness

My L90 has **no auto-brightness option**. Could anyone please suggest a way to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The L90 lacks an ambient light sensor, so there is no true auto brightness method.

XDA user gdjindal has a unique tutorial for adding a pseudo-automatic function on the Optimus L9 (it'll most likely work on your phone as well): [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2279971)

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to use my app. It is real auto brightness. ["Auto Brightness by PP"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bestq.autobrightness&hl=en)

Comment: Tell us why we should use your app. Features, good reviews? I'm not just gonna follow a random link.

Comment: You can see on good rate (4.5-4.6), and positive review. Even though it has a few download count because I just put it into app store this year, but the range is going up. More feature please read in the app link, to prevent "too much promote app" rule. Thanks.